# CSS set background-image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I'm working on a project where I need to place a background image and have it appear as shown on the attachment.

Here is what I tried but the code does not working as it was intended. The image appears as full rectangle instead of the half rectangle. Which CSS rule should I set to achieve desired output?

[image: the background image to be placed]

```css
section{
    background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/300x100");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

```html
<section>A section.</section>
```

Comment: This doesn't really help us. What's not working for you?

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your title should be a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so that we can see the issue

Comment: @ j08691  see the example on the image attached there , which css rule should i write to achieve desired outputs?